# angularJS custom directive for timepicker not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have a custom directive for my timepicker just using element. The input is working and the label that I custom made as well however the timepicker plugin that I used will not work. I am using this plugin for my timepicker: http://timepicker.co/options/.

This is my html:

```
  <apple-timepicker label="Time Picker: " a-id="time" ng-model="fieldTime" ></apple-timepicker>{-fieldTime-}
```

And my custom directive js:

```
  apple.directive('appleTimepicker', function(){
var linker = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    $(element).timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
        interval: 15, // 15 minutes
        change: function(time) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                // the input field
                var element = $(this), text;
                // get access to this TimePicker instance
                var timepicker = element.timepicker();
                text = timepicker.format(time);
                ngModel.$setViewValue(text);
            });
        }
    });
};
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<label for="inputTimepicker">{-fieldLabel-}</label>'+
                '<div>'+
                    '<input type="text" id={-fieldId-} ng-model="fieldTime" readonly="true"/>'+
                '</div>',
    scope: {
        fieldLabel: '@label',
        fieldId: '@aId',
        fieldTime: '=ngModel'
    },
    controller: ['$scope',function($scope) {

    }],
    link: linker
};
});
```

Comment: Elaborate "not working"? Do you get an error? Is something even displayed?

Comment: @user2341963. The input text will appear however the timepicker plugin won't work.

Comment: why is the input `readonly`? Shouldn't plugin be bound to the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your linker function needs to get the input. Not the base div element:

```
element.find('input').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
        interval: 15, // 15 minutes
        change: function (time) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                // the input field
                var element = $(this);//, text;
                // get access to this TimePicker instance
                var timepicker = element.timepicker();
                var text = timepicker.format(time);
                ngModel.$setViewValue(text);
            });
        }
    });
```

Also, There's no reason to wrap element in a jquery object. It's already wrapped in a jquery lite object.